# Error creating a Master/Detail Flow app in Android Studio 1.4

Tags: android, android-activity, android-6.0-marshmallow

I've recently upgraded to Android Studio 1.4.

Following tutorials on the web, I've come along some that mention the Master/Detail Flow template.

However, creating such a template, I don't get expected results.

[image]

This is how the template looks when created. Lots of errors are present. Also, in the tutorials I follow, Android Studio should create at least 4 Java files by default (none are created here)?

I target Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) and the current state of my SDK Manager can be seen below.

What could be cause of this problem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually wait, untill the Gradle Build was finished?

You should see at the very bottom, that or if it is working on something and it'll tell you what it's working on.